# pass Command-line argument to c string and pointer in c

Tags: c++, pointers, arguments

I want to write a program that use command-line argument and pass it to c string array, and assign first position to a pointer and also last position, and using these pointers swap reverse the string, but i got error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void revString(char const tempString,int length);
char *strcpy(char* s, char* t);   

int main(int argc,char const *argv[])
{
    if (argc!=2)
    {
        cerr<<"Usage: "<<argv[0]<<" String\n";
        return 1;
    }

    char tempString[100];
    strcpy(tempString, argv[1]);

    int length = strlen(argv[1]); 

    revString(tempString,length);  

    return 0; 
}


void revString(char const tempString,int length)    
{   
    char *arrFront;
    char *arrRear;
    int i = 0, r = 0;
    while(*(arrFront+length)!='\0')
        length++;
    for(i=length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        *(arrRear+r) = *(arrFront+i);
        r++;
    }
    *(arrRear+r) = '\0';  
}
```

Comment: No context, no error message, mistagging... Aaaargh!

Answer (score 0):

In the function `revString`, `tempString` shouldn't be `char const`, the prototype of it should be:

```
void revString(const char* tempString,int length)
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And you don't need to add the declaration of `strcpy` as it's already in the header `<cstring>`